Cloudwatch SES reporting
Since few days, I'm sending metrics about my SES sending with a Configuration set and an Event destination to Cloudwatch.
For each of my mails, I add some tags like campaign, language, etc...
In Cloudwatch, I can see one line per combinaison of my tags

In Graphed metrics, I can create a new Math "SUM(METRICS()" to get the total of mails sent.
But my goal is to create custom lines, one specific campaign, whatever the language or the other tags. I've tried to create a custom expression :
SUM(SEARCH('{SES,campaign} MetricName="Send" campaign="my-campaign"', 'Average', 3600))
But it show me no line, do you know why?
Thanks

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.
